# How to get average of columns in db from laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

My transaction table has 4 columns (others are irrelevant for query)

- trans_id : integer, pk
- user_id: integer,fk
- amount: double
- bus_id:integer

I'm trying to get the average amount that they spend by averaging the `amount` column, but my the response keeps coming as column not found.

```
  public function userDollarAverage(Request $request)
  {
    $business = $request->input('bus_id');
    $user = $request->input('user_id');
    $getAvgAmount = Transactions::whereColumn([
      ['user_id', '=', $user],
      ['bus_id', '=', $business]
      ])->avg('amount');
    return response()->json(['average' => $getAvgAmount]);
  }
```

my migration

```
  Schema::create('Transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('transaction_id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('user_id')->on('users');
            $table->integer('bus_id')->nullable();
            $table->double('amount')->nullable();
        });
```

json I'm passing

```
{
    "user_id": 51,
    "bus_id": 1
}
```

they are also all listed in my model under 
    `protected $fillable = [];`

but im still getting error:

- Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '51' in 'where clause' (SQL: select avg(`amount`) as aggregate from `transactions` where (`user_id` = `51` and `bus_id` = `1`)) in file C:\Users\Jermayne\API\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php on line 664
- I cant figure out why I'm getting unknown column '51'

Comment: why are you calling `whereColumn`? you are not comparing columns to one another ... also `whereColumn` would be looking for a key => value array of column => column to compare

Comment: I misunderstood the use of `whereColumn()` I thought it was used to add an array and use multiple columns in a `where()`

Comment: ahh I needed to use `where()` instead of `whereColumn()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `whereColumn` to `where` and you should be on your way.

`whereColumn` is for comparing columns to one another.